# Sharepoint 2013 Icon Issues?

Tags: sharepoint

[SharePoint icon images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfX0A.jpg)

The middle set is when you open the datepicker. I'm not too sure what the upper left is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This typically happens when SP CSS files are not loaded properly. Try clearing browser cache and reloading the page. If the problem persist, check if there is any permission issue that is causing access denied error while loading the CSS files.